# Why does shellcheck fail when a source file is representing the variables at the top of a script?

Tags: bash, scripting, shellcheck

**Ubuntu 16.04

Bash 4.3.48**

Why does `shellcheck` fail when a source file is representing the *$variables* at the top of a script?

Here is a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

. .sourcefile

echo "Today is ${day}."
```

Here is my source file:

```
day="Monday"
```

Here is the reply from `shellcheck`:

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck start.sh

In start.sh line 5:
echo "Today is ${day}."
               ^-- SC2154: day is referenced but not assigned.
```

Is there a way to let `shellcheck` know the *$variables* are in the source file?

---

### **Here is what I did to make this work on Ubuntu 16.04**

@Dash-o explained the procedure below:

First, add the *source directive* on the line above the *source file* declaration like so:
`# shellcheck source=/path/to/sourcefile`

```
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck source=./.sourcefile
. .sourcefile

echo "Today is ${day}."
```

Next, execute `shellcheck` with the **-x** option before the script like so:
`shellcheck -x start.sh`

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh
```

When using the **-x** option, `shellcheck` will follow the *source file* declared directly below the *source directive*. When I executed the command, I received the following error:

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh
unrecognized option `-x'

Usage: shellcheck [OPTIONS...] FILES...
  -e CODE1,CODE2..  --exclude=CODE1,CODE2..  exclude types of warnings
  -f FORMAT         --format=FORMAT          output format
  -s SHELLNAME      --shell=SHELLNAME        Specify dialect (bash,sh,ksh)
  -V                --version                Print version information
```

@Bayou mentioned my OS needed a newer version of `shellcheck`. I checked my Ubuntu 16.04 installation. My server had `shellcheck` 0.3.7, which is the latest version Ubuntu 16.04 had to offer, so I grabbed the latest binary from the `shellcheck` developers and installed it.

```
me@myserver:~$ mkdir .work && cd .work
me@myserver:~/.work$ wget -q https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/releases/download/stable/shellcheck-stable.linux.x86_64.tar.xz
me@myserver:~/.work$ ls

shellcheck-stable.linux.x86_64.tar.xz

me@myserver:~/.work$ tar xvf shellcheck-stable.linux.x86_64.tar.xz

shellcheck-stable/README.txt
shellcheck-stable/LICENSE.txt
shellcheck-stable/shellcheck

me@myserver:~/.work$ sudo chown root: shellcheck-stable/shellcheck
me@myserver:~/.work$ sudo mv /usr/bin/shellcheck .
me@myserver:~/.work$ sudo mv shellcheck-stable/shellcheck /usr/bin/
me@myserver:~/.work$ cd ../
me@myserver:~$ rm -rf .work/
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -V

ShellCheck - shell script analysis tool
version: 0.7.1
license: GNU General Public License, version 3
website: https://www.shellcheck.net
```

I ran the command `shellcheck -x start.sh` and I received zero errors.

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh
```

I then forced `shellcheck` to give me a few errors. I added `cat $myVariable` to the end of my script.

```
me@myserver:~$ echo "cat \$myVariable" >> start.sh  
me@myserver:~$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/bash

# shellcheck source=./.sourcefile
. .sourcefile

echo "Today is ${day}."
cat $myVariable
```

I tested my theory and `shellcheck` followed my *sourcefile* and gave me errors I was expecting.

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh

In start.sh line 7:
cat $myVariable
    ^---------^ SC2154: myVariable is referenced but not assigned.
    ^---------^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
cat "$myVariable"

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2154 -- myVariable is referenced but not ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
```

Then I executed `shellcheck` without the **-x** option and to my surpise I received the following errors:

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck start.sh

In start.sh line 4:
. .sourcefile
  ^---------^ SC1091: Not following: ./.sourcefile was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).


In start.sh line 6:
echo "Today is ${day}."
               ^----^ SC2154: day is referenced but not assigned.


In start.sh line 7:
cat $myVariable
    ^---------^ SC2154: myVariable is referenced but not assigned.
    ^---------^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
cat "$myVariable"

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2154 -- day is referenced but not assigned.
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1091 -- Not following: ./.sourcefile was ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
```

So `shellcheck` updated to the latest version and without the **-x** option, will also give you an error about you mising the **-x** option on the command line. So I decided to comment out the *sourcefile directive* in my start.sh

```
me@myserver:~$ sed -i '3s/./#\ &/' start.sh
me@myserver:~$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/bash

# # shellcheck source=./.sourcefile
. .sourcefile

echo "Today is ${day}."
cat $myVariable
```

Now to see what `shellcheck` thinks

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh

In start.sh line 7:
cat $myVariable
    ^---------^ SC2154: myVariable is referenced but not assigned.
    ^---------^ SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean:
cat "$myVariable"

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2154 -- myVariable is referenced but not ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
```

Whaaaaa? So it seems the *sourcefile directive* is really not needed with my simple script or is shellcheck still seeing the *sourcefile directive* being commented out with the number sign as the number sign already starts the *sourcefile directive*? So I removed the *sourcefile directive* altogether and commented out the last line which references the *myVariable* variable that is not assigned in the sourcefile.

```
me@myserver:~$ sed -i '3d' start.sh
me@myserver:~$ sed -i '$d' start.sh
me@myserver:~$ cat start.sh
#!/bin/bash

. .sourcefile

echo "Today is ${day}."
```

Now to see what `shellcheck` reports:

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck -x start.sh
```

No errors with the **-x** option. Now to check if the *sourcefile directive* is not needed at the top of a simple shell script with latest version of `shellcheck` on Ubuntu 16.04, I executed `shellcheck` without the **-x** option.

```
me@myserver:~$ shellcheck start.sh

In start.sh line 3:
. .sourcefile
  ^---------^ SC1091: Not following: .sourcefile was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).


In start.sh line 5:
echo "Today is ${day}."
               ^----^ SC2154: day is referenced but not assigned.

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2154 -- day is referenced but not assigned.
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1091 -- Not following: .sourcefile was no...
```

So, in short, if `shellcheck` is not following your source file, update  `shellcheck` from the developer's github - (https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) and inform `shellcheck` there is a sourcefile to follow by using the **-x** option like so:

```
shellcheck -x script.sh
```

I hope this helps someone as this site helps me each and everyday!

Comment: The `"$(pwd)/"` part is not necessary. You can just use `. .sourcefile`.

Comment: @CuriousSam : I don't think that shell check is actually reading the sourced files. In the general case, Shellcheck can't know what file you are sourcing (imagine that you would source something like `.  /$(myprog $RANDOM)`. In particular in your case, shellcheck can not reasonibly derive the value of `pwd`.

Comment: I corrected the ```$(pwd)```.

Comment: Most of this should be an `Answer` instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Shellcheck is a static analysis tool. It does not handle dynamic paths (based on variables, or expressions). As an alternative, consider adding the source directive.

Example:

```
# shellcheck source=./lib.sh
source "$(find_install_dir)/lib.sh"
```

The source= directive tells shellcheck the location of the dynamically generated filename. From the question, this should be the (most likely, relative) location of the `.sourcefile`.

Documented in https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/blob/master/shellcheck.1.md

Comment: I read the documentation and tried it ```shellcheck source-path=./.sourcefile start.sh``` and it printed ```shellcheck: source-path=./.sourcefile: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)```. I also tired ```shellcheck source=./.sourcefile start.sh``` and it still failed. I must have the wrong syntax?

Comment: You have to insert a COMMENT into your script, just before the 'source' statement. This is NOT a command line parameter. Please take a look at the documentation link

Comment: Right on. All works perfectly now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I updated shellcheck again from the devs github and it seems as if the _sourcefile directive_ is not needed anymore, but the **-x** option is still needed to inform ```shellcheck``` to look for a souce file declared with the word ```source``` or a period ```.``` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Worth also noting that one could disable this check with `-e SC1090` opton.

Comment: This didn't work for me at first because the path to the sourced dir must be _relative to the dir you are in when you call `shellcheck -x path/to/script.sh`._ I figured that out then [wrote all about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75341911/4561887).

Comment: can `source=`  start from the home path?

Answer (score 6):

## VSCode fix

In VSCode, you can set a parameter in settings:

```json
{
  "shellcheck.customArgs": ["-x"]
}
```

Answer from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/534690/231320

Answer (score 4):

I use shellcheck 0.4.4 and it also says:

> In start.sh line 2:
>   . "$(pwd)"/.sourcefile
>   ^-- SC1090: Can't follow non-constant source. Use a directive to specify location.

That means you'll have to use absolute paths, but [newer](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1090) versions might support `-P`.

If you switched to a non-constant source, it will not work as well because `.sourcefile` needs a shebang and you have to add this file with `-x` as such:

```
shellcheck -x .sourcefile start.sh
```

It still will complain about:

> day="Monday"
>   ^-- SC2034: day appears unused. Verify it or export it.

Comment: That was purposely done to trigger the shellcheck warnings. ```day="Monday"``` is in the source file. While using shellcheck and calling for a source file inside the script, you have to add ```# shellcheck source=./.sourcefile.sh``` at the top of the script. You then tell shellcheck to look for the source with the -x on the command line ```shellcheck -x start.sh```

Comment: i _still_ get that even with `source "$HOME"/.bashrc`

Comment: @Fuseteam Try ```# shellcheck source=~/.bashrc```

Comment: same issue, in the end i just disabled it with `# shellcheck source=/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

It's more nuanced than [the main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58588622/4561887) suggests.

### How to properly fix the `SC1091` shellcheck error and get shellcheck to follow and check your sourced scripts

#### Summary

Put all 3 of these things together:

1. Ensure you use `shellcheck -x path/to/script.sh`.
2. Ensure you use a `# shellckeck source=path/to/sourced_script.sh` directive comment.
3. Ensure the path you use in the directive above is **relative to the directory you are in when calling `shellcheck -x path/to/script.sh`.**

#### Details

To remove the `SC1091 (info): Not following: path/to/script.sh was not specified as input (see shellcheck -x).` error, you need all 3 of these things:

1. Add `-x` when calling `shellcheck`:

   ```bash
   # ok
   shellcheck -x path/to/script.sh

   # NOT ok
   shellcheck path/to/script.sh
   ```
2. Add the proper `shellcheck` directive comment above the area of concern:

   Inside `path/to/script.sh`:

   ```bash
   # ok

   # shellcheck source=bash/sound_bell_lib.sh
   . "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/sound_bell_lib.sh"

   # NOT ok
   . "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/sound_bell_lib.sh"
   ```
3. Ensure the path you use inside your `shellcheck source=` directive comment is **relative to the path you are in when you call `shellcheck`!**

   If:

   1. Your script is at `~/dev/script.sh`.
   2. The script you are sourcing from `~/dev/script.sh` is at `~/dev/script2.sh`.
   3. You are in the `~` directory when running the shellcheck command.
   4. The shellcheck command you are running is `shellcheck -x dev/script.sh`

   Then, the shellcheck directive path you must use is `dev/script2.sh`, like this:

   ```bash
   # shellcheck source=dev/script2.sh
   . "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/script2.sh"
   ```

   *But*, if you are in the `~/dev` dir when running the shellcheck command, and the shellcheck command you are running is `shellcheck -x script.sh`, then the shellcheck directive path you must use is `./script2.sh`, or simply `script2.sh`, instead, like this:

   ```bash
   # shellcheck source=./script2.sh
   . "$SCRIPT_DIRECTORY/script2.sh"
   ```